# A shopkeeper sells a T-shirt at a profit...

Tags: arithmetic

A shopkeeper sells a T shirt at a profit of $16$%. Had he bought  it at $4$% less and sold it at Rs $12$ more, he would have made a profit of $25$%. Find the cost price of T-shirt.

My Approach:

Let the cost Price of T-shirt be Rs.$x$.

Profit=$16$%.
Then,
$S.P_1$=$x+\frac {16}{100} x$
             $$x+\frac {4x}{25}$$
              $$\frac {29x}{25}$$.

I got paused from here. Please help me to continue.

Comment: First you need to make sure the profit percentage is based on the cost, not on the selling price.  Often it is defined on selling price, so the cost would be $0.84$ of the selling price.  Assuming the profit is on cost, your $P_1$ is correct.  There appears to be text missing from the last two expressions.  It is not clear what they refer to.

Comment: @ Ross Millikan, Those expressions refer to $S.P_1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint assuming profits are defined as percent of cost:  You need to turn the second sentence into an equation.  If he had bought it for $4\%$ less, what price did he pay?  If he sold it for $12$ more, he sold it for $1.16x+12$  Now write that the profit is $25\%$ and you have an equation for $x$